# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript

I have this code giving me the strange error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined
```

This is the inside of a jQuery plugin to show a google map in a popup.
I was using the code somewhere else, where it worked fine - the only difference here seems to be that I'm now using it in a Popup window. Am I missing a scope issue or something?
All the variables like geocoderParams and latlng are filled like they should.
Googling the the error message turned up nothing valuable.

The error message gets fired when the google.maps.Map() is called.

```
self = $(this)
self.hide()

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder
geocoderParams =
  address: self.data('address') || settings.address
  region: settings.region

results = geocoder.geocode geocoderParams, (results, status) ->

if status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK
  latlng = results[0].geometry.location

  mapOptions =
    mapTypeControl: false
    overviewMapControl: false
    zoom: settings.zoomLevel
    center: latlng
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

  map = new google.maps.Map(self, mapOptions)

self.show()
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I looked up `google.maps.Map()` and the [Google reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) says that the first parameter should be a `mapDiv:Node` which is the container for the map and is typically a `div` element.

You are passing `$(this)` which is likely a jQuery object which is not what Google maps is expecting.  I don't know the rest of your code, but perhaps you should just be passing `this` instead of `$(this)`.

Comment: If you just pass it a document.getElementById("my_div_id") it works fine too.

Comment: It also works if you add .get(0) to your jQuery element.

Comment: @user1912899 -no point in doing `$(this).get(0)` when just plain `this` works.  Why create a jQuery object you don't need it?

Answer (score 31):

If you're using jQuery, you need to pass the vanilla `HTMLElement` (e.g. `Node`) instead of the jQuery selection (e.g. `Array`/`NodeList`) which the `$()` query returns.

if you add a console command:

```
console.log(self);
```

it will return something like:

```
[ ▶ <div id="map_canvas"></div> ]
```

to get the value from the jQuery array, replace:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(self, mapOptions)
```

with:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(self[0], mapOptions)
```

Answer (score 20):

I encountered this error when trying to initiate the map with something like this:

```
map = new google.maps.Map($('#map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

I was able to solve it by selecting the first (and only) item that the selector returns by adding `[0]` after the selector:

```
map = new google.maps.Map($('#map-canvas')[0], mapOptions);
```

Comment: @mcflause this is no weird hack, the $ function just returns a list, the [0] selects the first one