# GoogleMap Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, backbone.js, geocoding

I am trying to display google map using backbonejs below.

```
define([
'require',
'backbone',
'text!../templates/list.html',
], function(Require, Backbone, Template){
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        template: _.template(Template),
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            var self = this;
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            self.initMap();
        },
        initMap: function(){
            var target = { lat: 1.098706, lng: 104.026971 };
            var mapOption = {zoom: 12, center: target };
            var mapElem = $(".container").find("#map-canvas");
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElem, mapOption);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: target,
                map: map
            });
        },
    });
```

});

After render finish, I got this error:

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined*

I am still confused about where **'position'** came from.
I've tried some solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483023/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-position-of-undefined) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483023/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-position-of-undefined)

Have you some ideas to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Use the debugger. Check the affected .js files and the line number. It should give you an idea.

Comment: Unnecessary `var self = this;` This is a bad practice. Even if it was necessary there are proper ways to fix context in JavaScript

Comment: Where does `$(".container")` come from?

Comment: @TJ I use `$(".container")` to get the DOM.
`<div class="container">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%; height:500px"></div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
var mapElem = $(".container").find("#map-canvas");
```

to

```
var mapElem = $(".container").find("#map-canvas")[0];
```

Comment: if I use `$(".container").find("#map-canvas")[0];` the result is **undefined**. Because that I used `$(".container").find("#map-canvas");` to got the DOM.